# How do I convert 15-minute data to time series in datetime format so I can plot it using quantmod?

Tags: r, datetime, timestamp, time-series, quantmod

So I got this data that I want to convert into xts so I can plot it using quantmod. (It is 15m chart)

```
 > sample
                    Date   Open   High   Low  Close Vol.at.Price Volume
515 2016-06-15 pm 1:15:00 1.7381 1.7600 1.710 1.7399       1.7399 176000
516 2016-06-15 pm 1:30:00 1.7389 1.7400 1.725 1.7350       1.7350 152900
517 2016-06-15 pm 1:45:00 1.7350 1.7650 1.720 1.7550       1.7550 179900
518 2016-06-15 pm 2:00:00 1.7550 1.7600 1.740 1.7500       1.7500 130800
519 2016-06-15 pm 2:15:00 1.7550 1.7800 1.745 1.7800       1.7800 188400
520 2016-06-15 pm 2:30:00 1.7800 1.7899 1.730 1.7300       1.7300 256700
521 2016-06-15 pm 2:45:00 1.7300 1.7800 1.730 1.7664       1.7664 151900
522 2016-06-15 pm 3:00:00 1.7600 1.7700 1.740 1.7600       1.7600  74100
523 2016-06-15 pm 3:15:00 1.7501 1.8000 1.750 1.7850       1.7850 232300
524 2016-06-15 pm 3:30:00 1.7900 1.8200 1.760 1.7600       1.7600 183300
525 2016-06-15 pm 3:45:00 1.7600 1.7700 1.730 1.7400       1.7400 151600
526 2016-06-15 pm 4:00:00 1.7400 1.7599 1.650 1.7150       1.7150 443500
527 2016-06-15 pm 4:15:00 1.7100 1.7100 1.710 1.7100       1.7100   4628
528 2016-06-15 pm 6:30:00 1.7100 1.7100 1.710 1.7100       1.7100   2000
529 2016-06-15 pm 7:00:00 1.6900 1.6900 1.680 1.6900       1.6900   1050
530 2016-06-15 pm 8:00:00 1.6900 1.6900 1.690 1.6900       1.6900    100
> class(sample)
   [1] "data.frame"
```

At first, I thought using xts function would do the job but then I realized it just cuts off minutes part.

```
> sampled.after<-xts(sample[2:ncol(sample)],as.Date(sample$Date))
> sampled.after
             Open   High   Low  Close Vol.at.Price Volume
2016-06-15 1.7381 1.7600 1.710 1.7399       1.7399 176000
2016-06-15 1.7389 1.7400 1.725 1.7350       1.7350 152900
2016-06-15 1.7350 1.7650 1.720 1.7550       1.7550 179900
2016-06-15 1.7550 1.7600 1.740 1.7500       1.7500 130800
2016-06-15 1.7550 1.7800 1.745 1.7800       1.7800 188400
2016-06-15 1.7800 1.7899 1.730 1.7300       1.7300 256700
2016-06-15 1.7300 1.7800 1.730 1.7664       1.7664 151900
2016-06-15 1.7600 1.7700 1.740 1.7600       1.7600  74100
2016-06-15 1.7501 1.8000 1.750 1.7850       1.7850 232300
2016-06-15 1.7900 1.8200 1.760 1.7600       1.7600 183300
2016-06-15 1.7600 1.7700 1.730 1.7400       1.7400 151600
2016-06-15 1.7400 1.7599 1.650 1.7150       1.7150 443500
2016-06-15 1.7100 1.7100 1.710 1.7100       1.7100   4628
2016-06-15 1.7100 1.7100 1.710 1.7100       1.7100   2000
2016-06-15 1.6900 1.6900 1.680 1.6900       1.6900   1050
2016-06-15 1.6900 1.6900 1.690 1.6900       1.6900    100
```

How do I convert it into timeseries so I can plot candle chart?

Comment: `as.Date` returns just the date portion of the timestamp. Use `as.POSIXct` to keep the full timestamp.

Comment: It still gives me the same result except showing EDT. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`as.Date` returns just the date portion of the timestamp. Use `as.POSIXct` to keep the full timestamp. In addition, you need to provide a `format` argument so that `as.POSIXct` understands your date format. Without the `format` argument, it just truncates the timestamp to the date portion. Here are a few examples:

**`as.Date` returns date only**

```
as.Date("2016-06-15 pm 1:15:00")
```

> ```
> [1] "2016-06-15"
> ```

**`as.POSIXct` without `format` argument returns date plus default timezone**

```
as.POSIXct("2016-06-15 pm 1:15:00")
```

> ```
> [1] "2016-06-15 PDT"
> ```

**Add correct `format` to `as.POSIXct` in order to get full timestamp**

```
as.POSIXct("2016-06-15 pm 1:15:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %p %I:%M:%S")
```

> ```
> [1] "2016-06-15 13:15:00 PDT"
> ```

See the help for `strptime` for details on how to interpret the `format` argument above.

**Add correct `format` and `tz` to `as.POSIXct` in order to get full timestamp and correct timezone**

Note that `as.POSIXct` also added my local timezone to the result (PDT). You should therefore probably also add a timezone argument to make sure that the correct timezone is applied (especially if you have quotes from exchanges in different timezones). For example:

```
as.POSIXct("2016-06-15 pm 1:15:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %p %I:%M:%S", tz="America/New_York")
```

> ```
> [1] "2016-06-15 13:15:00 EDT"
> ```